# Get the most recent year and least recent year of each foreign key and calculate

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

I'm calculating the growth rate **between** two time ranges (**5 years**) using the formula below:

```
growth rate = ((2016 net income/2012 net income) * 1/(5 years)) - 1
```

My `IncomeStatements` table is somehow structured like this:

```
id | stockid | year | netincome
1  | 1       | 2016 | 235235346
2  | 1       | 2015 | 432434545
..2014-2013 rows
5  | 1       | 2012 | 324324234
6  | 2       | 2016 | 234235234
7  | 2       | cycle continues..
```

How can I select the **most recent** and **most past** years (2016 and 2012) of each stock id (`FOREIGN KEY`) to apply the formula and then the result is updated in the `growthrate` column in the `stock` table?

Below is my incomplete code. Kindly help me improve it or provide workarounds since I'm new to SQL.

```
UPDATE stock SET growthrate = (Help)  
FROM IncomeStatements WHERE IncomeStatements.stockid= stock.id
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: sql-server 2014 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to get the first and last values for the year and net income.  You can do this with window functions.

The rest is just arithmetic:

```
with i as (
      select distinct stockid,
             first_value(year) over (partition by stockid order by year) as year_first,
             first_value(year) over (partition by stockid order by year desc) as year_last,
             first_value(netincome) over (partition by stockid order by year) as netincome_first,
             first_value(netincome) over (partition by stockid order by year desc) as netincome_last
      from incomestatements i

update s
    set growthrate = ((i.netincome_last - i.netincome_first) / nullif(i.year_last - i.year_first, 0)) - 1
    from stock s
         i
         on s.stock_id = i.stock_id;
```